# Access Custom outlook 2013 ribbon at runtime using c#

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-2013

I have created 2 different add-ins for outlook 2013.

In first add-in, i have custom ribbon and custom task pane.

In second add-in , i have custom ribbon and on click of that ribbon i want to hide first add-in.

So i tried to hide custom task pane and it worked.

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane mtPane in Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.ToList())
  {
   if (mtPane.Title == "CustomTaskPane")
    {
      mtPane.Visible = false;
    }
  }
```

but i am not sure how to hide or access custom ribbon at run time in another add-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access a custom Ribbon UI which belongs to other add-ins. Instead, you can define a public property or method in the add-in you need to reach. So, you will manage its custom UI through public properties and methods defined on the add-in. See [Walkthrough: Calling Code in an Application-Level Add-in from VBA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608614.aspx) for more information.

Comment: ok. now if i have updated my solution. i have created two buttons in context menu ribbon. on click of one button, want to disable other button. so is it possible?

Comment: No, it is not. You can call a public method in another add-in which created the button you need to disable. In the method you can call the Invalidate or InvalidateControl method of the IRibbonUI inteface to get your callbacks invoked.

Comment: Now both button in custom ribbon ui belongs to same addin. still it is not possible?

Comment: Well, if both buttons comes from the single add-in you can change the state at runtime using callbacks.

Comment: Now it is working fine. But have a look at one more case: I have to disable ribbon button as well as Custom task pane. So after myRibbon.Invalidate(); method, i am setting custom task pane visibility to false. and it is working. but if i toggle my button, then on each toggle - it is firing my other button event